# Disable Firebase storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Is there a command or parameter to disable FireBase's storage option? I never need it and it adds extra time to the deployment process that I don't need. Or should I just create a new project and start over?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do not implement the storage library into your gradle file, then your app will not connect at all with Firebase Storage and your build will be a slightly faster since it won't be loading all Firebase Storage library